# My motorcycle won't start at all why?

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, suzuki

Something is draining my battery and my bike won't start. If it's the relays which one is it? My motorcycle doesn't crank at all. it makes a buzzy noise when I press the start button. It sounds like there's a power shortage. I have a Suzuki sv 650 year 2007.

if it's my starter how would I know if so how can I replace it where is it located or is it just the 1 on the throttle?

Comment: How old is your battery? Did you try replacing/recharging your battery?

Comment: yes the battery is replaced brand new I'm thinking it might be the starter if not the rectifier regulator. is that possible but the noise is coming from under the gas tank kind of under the carburetors hard to tell but the noise is under the gas tank that's all I know.

Comment: if its the starter switch relay how would I know he's like I said under the gas tank every time I press the start button or try to twist the throttle? Please help me if you can ASAP I appreciate it thank you

Comment: I'll ask someone with enough knowledge and then get back to you. Did you try jump starting the bike??

Comment: jump starting may not work because its EFI.

Comment: in the beginning I jump started the bike any bad signs there?

Comment: what's does efi stand for or is that an abbreviation for some thing

Comment: the noise sounds like it's coming right from the gas tank saving possible is there any fuses in there

Comment: the buzzy noise when it makes that buzzy noise it just comes randomly and when that happens it usually drains my battery don't know what that is

Comment: There are not direct issues with jump starting a bike although its not recommended. If you ask why, simply because its not ment to be started like that.

Comment: One of my friend mentioned that the buzzing noise is caused by the starter motor running just fine. But its teeth not catching with the other side which is supposed to crank the engine. Its not a very serious issue and any mechanic can take out the electric starter unit, realign the mechanisms and put it back in. everything should be back to normal. Cheers!

Comment: EFI stands for electronic fuel injection. It means unlike the old Carburetors the efi systems use a electronic pump to inject the fuel into the cylinder. It is, needless to say controlled by a ECU (electronic control unit). So a bike such as your's might run for a few mins when you jumpstart it, but will stall and stop soon. Since u mentioned shortage of power, i suggest that you should make sure that the battery leads are not touching the body of the bike so that a short or drain is happening. try covering it with a plastic bag so that the battery does not touch any metal in the bike

Comment: well solve the problem and it was as simple as son of a gun it was the safety control switch. I mean i also had to bypass it .jacked up so it starts and runs sounds like an animal apreciate your guyses help also to their were a few fuses that needed to be replaced and I had to replug the ECU  that's why I was receiving a short the power signals were all  spaced out.

Comment: Cheers!! Ride safe..

Answer (score 7):

For a start your starter motor is the cylindrical thing to the right of #9 in this picture
[image: starter location]

I'd check it has a good connection to ground (is the resistance between the - negative terminal of battery to the outer steel of the starter lots less than 1?)

Whip the seat off and check the starter relay and see if theres any corrosion and it's nice and tight. It's the translucent covered thing immediately up and to the left of the positive battery terminal.
[image: relay location]

What happens when you try and push start it? Do the pistons feel like they are pumping around when you let the clutch out? If they don't then maybe something has seized and the starter doesn't have the power to crank everything around so it just buzzes.

Lastly, it's probably not because if you have a green connector failure then I don't think any current would make it to the starter motor, but under the fuel tank there is a green connector that is famous for corroding and causing starting issues.